# Datepicker Actual

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

tengo una duda, actualmente estoy usando Bootstrap 4 y Jquery 3.3.1 el caso es que necesito añadir a varios formularios el poder elejir fechas pero no haciendo tipico `<input type="date"/>` ya que el formato que me da por defecto no es el que quiero y no puedo cambiarlo (a menos de que haya alguna forma de hacerlo lo he intentado casi todo), alguien sabría como hacer un datepicker de forma dinámica o algo lo necesito algo urgente.

muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Echale un ojo a [bootstrap-datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Hola Juank. Aqui las preguntas requieren informacion del trabajo realizado por tu parte. Pulsa en [edit] para añadir lo que has intentado para ver los errores que tuviste, ya que nosotros ayudamos sobre tus problemas conretos, no tareas. Ten en cuenta que la urgencia no es factor relevante para las preguntas del sitio y que las preguntas con una informacion clara ([mcve]) son respondidas mucho antes que las que no presentan nada. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

`introducir el código aquí`Si quieres darle otro formato deberías tener algún plugin como sería datepicker de Jquery UI, si tienes en tu proyecto el plugin con su CSS bastaría con un `<input type="text" class="datepicker"/>` y un pequeño bloque javascript para que funcione, algo como esto:

```
  <script>
    $( function() {
      $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
  </script>
```

Si te fijas el input es de tipo texto, para que pueda coger el estilo de Datepicker, de lo contrario si es de tipo `date` la mayoría de los navegadores modernos utilizarán un su formato para elegir fecha como te ha pasado seguro con Chrome o Edge, no te preocupes por la entrada al ser de tipo text ya que eso se regula con el js del mismo plugin.
te recomiendo le eches un vistazo a la documentación de Datepicker en http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ saludos

Comment: Hola Vicente. Gracias por responder pero no todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas. Han de contener informacion de su trabajo para ayudarle sobre ello, no a hacer investigacion y resolucion por él. Para la proxima, intenta esperar a que el autor complete la pregunta y reporta la pregunta para su cierre si no tiene calidad suficiente. Un saludo !

Comment: la cosas es que dice que la funcion `datepicker();` no está definida asi que he tenido que pillar jqueryUI para ello, pero aun asi gracias :)